# How to make the overlay element responsive

Tags: html, css

In a 1920*1080 screen, the play button and the waves outside are exactly inside the laptop image screen and everything is fine.

But when I resize the screen width the play button moves independently to the laptop screen and gets out of the screen of the laptop image. it also doesn't change its size so it gets ugly!

How can I make this responsive to the size of the laptop image screen and fix the play button to stay inside the laptop screen?

I tried flexbox but it seems that I need a hand...Please help...

Any Suggestions Would Be Greatly Appreciated...

```css
.videoContainer {
  padding-top: 14rem;
}


.video-play-button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 44px;
  /* background: #fa183d; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 18px 20px 18px 28px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  
}

.video-play-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ba1f24;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.video-play-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fa183d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.video-play-button:hover:after {
  background-color: darken(#fa183d, 10%);
}

.video-play-button img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.video-play-button span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 32px solid #fff;
  border-top: 22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
}

.video-box-computer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  top: 180px
}

.videoImage {
  width: 45%;
}

.waves-block {
    position: absolute;
    float: center; 
    width: 384px;
    width: 24rem;
    height: 384px;
    height: 24rem;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
}

.waves-block .waves {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24rem;
    height: 24rem;
    background: rgb(178, 163, 214, 0.2);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 320px;
    -webkit-animation: waves 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: waves 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.waves-block .wave-1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
 .waves-block .wave-2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

.waves-block .wave-3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes waves {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
        transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.9;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="videoContainer">

          <div class="video-box-computer">
              <img class="videoImage" src="http://demo.graygrids.com/themes/beam/imgs/macbook.png">
          </div>

          <a id="play-videoA" class="video-play-button" href="#">
          <span></span>

          <div class="waves-block">
            <div class="waves wave-1"></div>
            <div class="waves wave-2"></div>
            <div class="waves wave-3"></div>
          </div>

          </a>

 </section>
```

Comment: You might want to look at flexbox for this, handles centering with a lot less effort: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I used flexbox in the container but it seems that I need a hand to make it work..

Comment: Hey, is that a single page? Or could this content be inside something? This completely changes the approach to what can be done.

Comment: beforehand, I can say that your great villains are these now: .video-box-computer {
top: 180px;
}
.videoContainer {
padding-top: 14rem;
}

Comment: It's just a section of a landing page...but there are no overriding classes I think!

Comment: So all you need to do is centralize it all within the section.videoContainer? Will this section be 100% of the width of the screeen on the final page?

Comment: And also we need the play button and the waves to be responsive to the page size too.. the second question: Yes...